# How to have a ordered list with text indent for multi-line items

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I'm trying to create an ordered list with the second line of `<p>` at the same indent as the first one.

However, that doesn't seem to work with the `display: inline` property. But if I remove the `display: inline;`, the `::before item` and `p` are not on the same line.

How can I have the `::before` and the `p` on the same line with the correct text indent?

--

**With `display: inline;`:**
[image: Result of display inline]

**Without `display: inline;`:**
[image: Result of no display inline]

Here's my code.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ol li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
  padding-right: 24px;
  display: inline;
}

ol p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to position the counter absolute within the li and give the before pseudo element and the p elements the same top margin (browsers may set this, this snippet sets it to 1em).

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
}

ol li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

ol li p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 24px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ol li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
  padding-right: 24px;
  display: inline;
}

ol p {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 24px;
}
```

This will indent the text in the p elements by 24 pixels, matching the distance between the `::before` element and the start of the p element's text. This will give you the desired layout, with the `::before` and p elements on the same line and the text of the p elements indented to match the `::before` elements.

Note that you do not need to remove the `display: inline;` property in order to achieve this layout. You can leave this property as-is, and the text-indent property will still work as expected.